# Windows - Use part of the memory as a partition

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, memory

I have some machines processing some repetitive stuff. They have way more memory than needed, and a "faster disk" would come handy. So I'm thinking if there's a way I could use say half of the memory as disk. I want to access it as a partition or volume, for example as E: in a way similar to when you map /dev/shm in linux. The machines are running Windows Server 2012. Is it possible? How?

My google skills seem to not be sharpened towards that, because any keywords I use take me to low memory issues or disk partitioning and the like. :(

Comment: It's called a RAM disk, e.g. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsinternals/2017/08/25/how-to-create-a-ram-disk-in-windows-server/

Comment: @ward is correct, a ramdisk is the term and the blog posted provided is the correct approach, ward you should convert your comment to an Answer so it can be marked as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "RAM disk" - it's been around since the days of DOS...

Here's a good MS Technet Blog post about setting up a RAM disk on Windows:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsinternals/2017/08/25/how-to-create-a-ram-disk-in-windows-server/

(I originally answered as a comment because I'm not sure this is on-topic for ServerFault - it's more a general Windows question, not specific to servers.)

Comment: Showing my age here but we had ram disks for CP/M :)

Comment: Many thanks! Definitely knowing the right term to search makes all the difference, searching for RAM disk I get a lot of what I wanted. And yeah I was in doubt also if I should ask in superuser or serverfault, but then I decided that this is not an operation regular users usually do, it's more something a professional would do for specific needs, so I decided to post here. :$ But if anyone thinks it's better to migrate there I wouldn't oppose.

Comment: @Chopper3  Don't get me started on back in the day... or I'll have to trot out the story of programming an HP3000 minicomputer over a 300baud dial-up line with a TI thermal terminal and optical "punch cards"  ...wait, I just did.  :)